# Variable substitution in TCL inside curly brace

Tags: tcl

I am trying to perform a variable substitution within curly braces which I understand is not feasible directly in TCL.

The code I am trying:

```
interface code -clip {$x1 $y1 $x2 $y2}
```

The interface code is a third party TCL function that has an option called clip which reads x1,y1,x2,y2 coordinates within curly braces.

I need to feed in the values of x1,y2 within the curly braces.

Comment: Use `interface code -clip [list $x1 $y1 $x2 $y2]`

Comment: Hi Glen. The interface code is essentially a third party tool command that uses the curly brace syntax. So I can change it to "[" . The command is more like cmd -option1 <xx> -option2 <yy> -clip {x1 y1 x2 y2}

Comment: There's nothing magical about braces. They are Tcl's non-interpolating quotes, like single quotes in the shell. This interface code just needs a single argument for the -clip option, so you need to group these 4 variables into a single element. I repeat, there's nothing magical about braces. You could also use double quotes: `interface code -clip "$x1 $y1 $x2 $y2"`. Tcl is a very simple language when it comes to syntax. There are only 12 rules. Read about the difference between double quotes and braces here: https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/Tcl.htm

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Tcl, the `{…}` syntax *technically* means “do no substitutions at all on this”. The command that the value gets passed to might do its own thing with those characters, and those things might look a lot like substitution (e.g., if it is evaluating the word as a script, which is what `if` and `for` and `while` and … do), but Tcl's core syntax just leaves them alone and passes them through.

To get what you want, there's a few alternatives. You can do the substitutions before passing the value in — the command literally can't see that you've done this if you choose to do it — or you can get the command to do the substitutions (not a useful suggestion if it's third-party code, of course).

To do the substitutions yourself, you might do *one* of these:

```
interface code -clip [list $x1 $y1 $x2 $y2]
```

```
interface code -clip "$x1 $y1 $x2 $y2"
```

```
interface code -clip [subst {$x1 $y1 $x2 $y2}]
```

The first option is good if the command takes a list (which your case looks like; it appears to be a coordinate list). The second option is good if the command takes a string. The third option is good when things are getting complicated! It's usually a good idea to try to avoid very complicated stuff; programs are difficult enough to write and read without deliberately making them even harder to understand.